# Koa and Twitter - "Thunking" does not work

Tags: javascript, twitter, thunk, koa

I've gotten some third party asynchronous functions to work with Koa through thunking, either by wrapping the function like so: `var thunkedFunction = function(params) { return function(callback) { originalFunction(params, callback) }; )` or using the node thunkify library.

However when I try this with ntwitter's stream like so:

```
var streamThunk = thunkify(tw.stream);
var stream = yield streamThunk("statuses/filter", {track: track});
```

I get the following error: "Cannot read property stream_base of undefined".

Digging deeper into ntwitter (built on node-twitter) I see that the Twitter.prototype.stream function calls this.options.stream_base, and this.options is defined when I call it normally i.e. `tw.stream(function(stream) {...});` but undefined when I thunk the function. Is there any reason that the function loses its scope when thunked, and is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that `thunkify` doesn't see the `tw` object.  So, the way it's designed, it has no way of knowing the context (`tw` in your case) of the function it's getting (`tw.stream`).

The function returned by `thunkify` will pass along whatever **`this`** context it's called with ([source: node-thunkify/index.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-thunkify/blob/master/index.js#L27)).

This means you should be able to change the second line in your example to:

```
var stream = yield streamThunk.call(tw, "statuses/filter", {track: track});
```

[Read more about `call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).